# Why does du command show wrong size of log directory?

Tags: linux, disk-space, du

I'm running:

```
du -h
```

These are the results:

```
112K    ./YaST2/storage-inst
172K    ./YaST2/storage-03
56K     ./YaST2/storage-02
48K     ./YaST2/storage-01
60K     ./YaST2/storage
64K     ./YaST2/control-03
64K     ./YaST2/control-02
64K     ./YaST2/control-01
64K     ./YaST2/control
11M     ./YaST2
2.8M    ./zypp
0       ./krb5
0       ./samba
75M     ./journal/cdb643da53b6499fa275a4527e973a40
75M     ./journal
0       ./private
0       ./mysql
0       ./tuned
100K    ./cups
34M     ./audit
0       ./chrony
4.0K    ./cepces
1008K   ./libvirt/qemu
1008K   ./libvirt
0       ./swtpm/libvirt/qemu
0       ./swtpm/libvirt
0       ./swtpm
4.0K    ./ipp-usb
0       ./speech-dispatcher
17M     ./updateTestcase-2023-08-18-14-05-42
17M     ./updateTestcase-2023-08-19-14-37-57
30G     .
```

Why is 30G usage reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `du` shows you directories only, `-h` does not change this behavior. The high usage you see for `.` is caused by non-directories (most likely regular files) directly inside `.`.

Use `du -a`:

> `-a`
> In addition to the default output, report the size of each file not of type directory in the file hierarchy rooted in the specified file. […]

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html))</sup>

```
du -ah .
```